# Self-adjoint operator with increasing sequence of eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

The spectral theorem says that if $A$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with compact inverse, then the eigenvectors of $A$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $H$. Furthermore each eigenvalue is real and $|\lambda_n|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now let us slightly change the conditions of the theorem. Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator with increasing sequence of eigenvalues $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2<...$ Is it true that the eigenvectors of $A$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $H$?

Comment: Do you mean "eigenvalue" in the strict sense of $Ax = \lambda x$, or do you mean it in a more general sense (e.g. $A - \lambda I$ fails to be invertible)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In the strict sense: $Ax=\lambda x$.

Comment: I suspect that there exists a modification of the $\phi(t) \mapsto t\phi(t)$ map described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators) which has an increasing sequence of eigenvalues whose eigenvectors fail to span the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)\oplus L^2[0,1]$. Write $\{e_n\}$ for the canonical basis of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. Now define $A$ by 
$$
Ae_n=\lambda_ne_n,
$$
and on the second component let $(Af)(t)=tf(t). $
Now the eigenvectors of $A$ are $\{e_n\}$, which do not span $H$; in fact, their orthogonal complement is infinite-dimensional. You can tweak the second component to make the spectrum of $A$ almost anything you want.

Comment: Martin, thank you very much for a very nice example! It means that this compact inverse condition in spectral theorem cannot be replaced by my suggested condition.

Comment: Indeed. Basically, you cannot learn much structure from just the eigenvalues.